# Is it good idea to set SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck on at the server level?

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl, virtualhost

Is it a good idea to set Apache's `SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck on` at the server level? Is it a better idea to set it just for a virtual host?

What are the pros and cons of this setting?

Comment: http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/NameBasedSSLVHostsWithSNI#Changes_in_configuration_to_use_SNI

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on why you are running a secure server. if you are using SNIV to get multiple virtual hosts on a single IP address, each with a different cert, does it matter if someone with a browser that does not support SNIV can connect to the first site with the wrong name? If it does, then you should set it to on. If it doesn't, set it to off.

See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_ssl.html#sslstrictsnivhostcheck

Comment: Ok, what happen if I have only one Virtual host with SSL and I move it as a first one and set `SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off`? Will works SNI-aware and SNI-unaware clients correctly?

What happen in case I have two Virtual Hosts with SSL and I set a.com as a first and b.com as a second and set `SSLStrictSNIVHostCheck off`? Will SVN-unaware clients for b.com works correctly with certificate for a.com?

Comment: The answer to all of those questions is on the link provided. It explains exactly what affect the setting will have in each situation. What I don't understand is how a subsequent VirtualHost block could ever be visited by an SSL client who is *not* on SNI, since that client would always be getting served by the default block, which is the reason for SNI in the first place.